# How to compare MDS and Cluster analysis in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing, mds

This is my first post on here so I hope I don't break any rules! I have a set of 30snps sampled from 450 individuals. I have performed an MDS on my dataset and a cluster analysis. In both cases I have obtained two distinct groups. I would like to see if the individuals in the two groups are the same both for the MDS and the cluster analysis. Do you have any suggestions on how I could solve this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Hi, I would suggest re-posting this question on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com with more details (what format is the data in? etc). Since this is very specific to bioinformatics and only marginally related to programming, you’ll probably get a better answer there.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you've got two vectors, you can see how they differ using `setdiff()`:

```
set1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
set2 <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

# what elements are in set1 but not in set2?
setdiff(set1, set2)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought of using the function table() but I don't know how to create the two vectors. 
For the MDS maybe I can use the $points (it is a non metric MDS), but for the cluster analysis I have no idea how to extract the data from the cluster analysis itself.
Sorry, I hope I am not too confusing!

Comment: If you update your original question to include some more details (e.g., sample data and the code that you're using to do the MDS and cluster analysis), people might be able to help further.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to manipulate my data in order to use the function setdiff. It worked!